# Invalid PDO MySQL Statement - Error in Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have the following PDO statement, which is one of several similarly constructed statements on the page. The rest are working fine, so I am confused as to why this one is stating invalid syntax.

```
$test_id = '1';
$option = 'a';
$ab_email = 'test@testing.com';

$stmt = $pdo_db->prepare("INSERT INTO `ab_tests_visitors` (test_id,option,visits,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email=?");
$stmt->execute(array($test_id,$option,1,$ab_email,$ab_email));
```

The schema for the database has 5 columns, 2 of which are indexes.

- visitor_id is int(10) and auto_increment, and also primary
- test_id is int(10)
- option is varchar(100)
- visits is int(10) and default of 1
- email is varchar(255) and unique

The error being given is:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option,visits,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email=?' at line 1'

Comment: try enclosing the fields in backticks (`)

Comment: Sidenote: 4 VALUES but 5 in array. Could be a factor, but won't fix your code. Edit: `option` is a reserved word. See answer below.

Comment: The last variable is for the SQL "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE", so it's not extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`option` is a [MySQL keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). If you want to use it as an identifier, make sure to always surround it with backticks (as you should do with identifiers anyway):

```
$stmt = $pdo_db->prepare("INSERT INTO `ab_tests_visitors` (`test_id`,`option`,`visits`,`email`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `email`=?");
```

Comment: As an additional note, I had just corrected my statement after reading another SO article. In addition to using backticks around reserved keywords, adding a prefix to variables used in the php code helps also, as part of my function was returning a browser name for $name rather what I was looking for. So all of the variables associated to this function are now prefixed with abt.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, in name of your column, you must use backticks `` ` `` around the column name (alt + 96)